# "Report as present" dialog says I'll be marked as "absent" rather than "present"

Tags: bug, status-review, moderator-tools, wording, moderation-history

In the moderator dashboard, there's an option to record yourself as absent / inactive. I did that a couple of days ago, but now I'm back from a holiday and wanted to report myself as present. There seems to be a copy-paste error in the following text (emphasis mine):

> By default, you will only be marked as **absent** for the current site

That's the same text as in the Absence Reporting dialog. If I understand the functionality correctly, "absent" should be replaced with "present".

[image]

Comment: You're not going on holiday again, right? You can't leave every 6 to 8 weeks ...

Comment: I am, quite soon in fact - trying to run three marathons in three days: https://rhoderaces.com/events/newport/ https://www.millbrookmarathon.com https://www.baa.org/races/boston-marathon/enter

Comment: Those would take me 6 to 8 weeks to finish. I'm rooted. Have fun, enjoy and I hope you can improve your PB.